# Remove outdated target framework (warning NETSDK1138)

Tags: .net-core

I get this warning when running `dotnet new -i "<some-template>"`:

```sh
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.100/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.EolTargetFrameworks.targets(28,5): warning NETSDK1138: The target framework 'netcoreapp1.0' is out of support and will not receive security updates in the future. Please refer to https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-support for more information about the support policy.
```

The link https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-support doesn't contain any information regarting `netcoreapp1.0`.

`dotnet --list-sdks` shows this result:

```sh
2.1.300 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
3.1.101 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
3.1.201 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
3.1.302 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
5.0.100 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

Does this mean I have to remove `2.1.300`?

According to the website, support for `2.1.300` ends on August 21, 2021.

**Update:**

This is the output of `dotnet --list-runtimes`:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.1 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.3 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.6 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.1 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.3 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.6 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Comment: `netcoreapp1.0.` is for .NET Core 1.0, which is EOL. Try to reinstall the templates, it  may help

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Thanks. This didn't fix it.